# require asdf failed in sbcl repl

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I meet the following error. Any clue?

CL-USER> (require "asdf")
NIL

But the page  https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Loading-ASDF said

The recommended way to load ASDF is via:

(require "asdf")
All actively maintained Lisp implementations now include a copy of ASDF 3 that you can load this way using Common Lisp’s require function.1

Answer (score 1):

The specification for [PROVIDE, REQUIRE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_provid.htm) says that the return value of `require` is implementation-dependant, but that it should signal an error if a module fails to be loaded. In your case, the `NIL` return value is not an error, but an indication that the operation succeeded.

Try `(asdf:make "optima")`, for example. Your environment should recognize the `ASDF:MAKE` symbol, but it might fail to load the `:optima` system. See [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) to download and install systems.

By the way, you rarely need to require `asdf` (you don't need to do it in SBCL nor in CCL, at least). To be sure, you might want to restart your Lisp environment and see if the ASDF package exists.